# Using addEventListener straight after createElement('div')

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm creating a page which displays a number of cats of the screen and for each click the counter will increment by one. The problem I'm running into is that right now for every click within the div it incriments the counter instead of just on the image itsself.

Here is the code:

```
     display: function () {

        for (i = 0, idx = 0; i < cats.image.length; i++, idx++) {

            formattedCatNames = HTMLcatName.replace("%data%", cats.name[i]);
            var catNames = formattedCatNames;

            formattedCatImages = HTMLcatImage.replace("%data%", cats.image[i]);
            var catImages = formattedCatImages;

            formattedCatCounter = HTMLcatCounter.replace("%data%", cats.clicks[i]);
            var catCounter = formattedCatCounter

            var elem = document.createElement('div');
            elem.innerHTML = catNames + catImages + catCounter;

            elem.addEventListener('click', (function(catIndex) {
                return function() {
                    cats.clicks[catIndex]++;
                };
            })(i));
            document.body.appendChild(elem);
        }
    },
}

cats.display();
```

I've tried modifying the events handler to something like this but the console states it's undefined:

```
    elem.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener('click', (function(catIndex) {
        return function() {
            cats.clicks[catIndex]++;
    };
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) on the containing element instead of attaching an event handler to each generated element?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of the elements. You need to iterate over the list and add the event listener to each one.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? For example if `cats.clicks` is undefined, then you can't increment the value of one of it's child elements.

Comment: @JamesHay cats.clicks isn't the problem, it's the fact that the event listener targets everything instead of just the images. But at any rate the error is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you are adding the `img` to the div using `innerHTML` so once the `innerHTML` is set you can query the div to get reference to the image inside it and add the click handler to that alone.

```
elem.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', (function (catIndex) {
    return function () {
        cats.clicks[catIndex]++;
    };
})(i));
```

Note: In case of multiple image elements inside the div you can refine the selector using a class or any other attribute